# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "estar en el ajo"?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, modismos

En el Diccionario de la Lengua Española, en la entrada [**ajo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1NsFSLJ) se recoge:

> 1. m. Planta de la familia de las liliáceas, de 30 a 40 cm de altura, con hojas ensiformes muy estrechas y bohordo con flores pequeñas y blancas. El bulbo es también blanco, redondo y de olor fuerte y se usa mucho como condimento.
>
> 2. m. Cada una de las partes o dientes en que está dividido el bulbo o cabeza de ajo.
>
> 3. m. Salsa o pebre que se hace con ajos para guisar y sazonar las viandas, y alguna vez suele tomar el nombre de la misma vianda o cosas con que se mezcla. *Ajo comino*.

y la expresión [**estar en el ajo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1NsFSLJ) como:

> Estar al corriente, estar al tanto de un asunto tratado reservadamente.

lo que no parece tener ninguna relación clara con las acepciones de la palabra.

¿Cuál es el origen de esta expresión?

Answer (score 3):

En la versión de 1783 del diccionario de la RAE se recoge la siguiente acepción de "ajo":

> AJO. met. y fam. Negocio, ó asunto que se está tratando entre varios: y así suele decirse: andar en el AJO, entrar en el AJO, menear el AJO.

Es decir, la frase viene sencillamente de que "ajo" era una metáfora de "negocio". Pero ¿de dónde viene esta metáfora? La única pista que he encontrado es en el diccionario español-francés de Oudin (1607), que recoge la siguiente expresión:

> El negocio huele à ajos, *l'affaire sent les aulx: on dit communement en François, Le mortier sent les aulx.*

Efectivamente, en el CORDE podemos leer:

> *A un pobre hombre escuchábale un señor de mala gana, y despidióle, diciendo que se desviase de allí, que olía a ajos. Respondió:*
>   *-El negocio huele a ajos, que no yo.*
>
> - Melchor de Santa Cruz de Dueñas, "Floresta española", España (1574)

Entiéndase como "negocio" lo contrario de "ocio", es decir, la ocupación de la persona en un momento dado, lo que está haciendo en ese instante. O según el diccionario de autoridades (1734), "término genérico con que se significa qualquiera ocupación, empleo ò trabajo". En el caso del ejemplo, el que dice la frase es un mendigo pidiendo limosna.

El origen de esta expresión podría estar en el siguiente cuento:

> *A una dama que era gran decidora no había persona que le hiciese comer ajo, ni cosa que supiese a él. Un galán que la servía hízole un banquete, y dijo al cocinero que, de cualquier manera que fuese, le hiciese comer ajo. El cocinero por más disfrazar el negocio, picó algunos ajos en el mortero, y, quitados de allí, hizo una salsa verde en el mismo mortero, y llevándola delante de la dama, al primer bocado paró, y dijo:
>
>   -¡Oh, hideputa el villano! ¡Cuál viene disfrazado de verde, como si no le conociésemos acá!*
>
> - Juan de Timoneda, "El sobremesa y alivio de caminantes", España (1562-1569)

En algún momento se sustituiría la palabra original "negocio" con su metáfora "ajo".